# Using the commands \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathresult

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

How do I use the commands `\pgfmathparse {tan (pi/3 r)} \pgfmathresult`
to draw the green line in the figure below?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=2]
\draw circle (1);
\draw[->] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) coordinate (x);
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);

\fill[fill=green!25] (0,0) -- (.2,0) arc (0:60:.2) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (60:1);
\draw[<-,red,line width=1pt] (60:1) -- (60:1 |- x);
\draw (0,0) -- (60:2);
%tangent
\draw[<-,green,line width=1pt] (60:2) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking or what is wrong with what you have, but here is how I would do it: Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` which invokes `\pgfmathparse` and uses the result from `\pgfmathresult`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\radius}{1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\YValue}{tan(deg(pi/3))*\radius}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=2]
\draw circle (1);
\draw[->] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) coordinate (x);
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);

\fill[fill=green!25] (0,0) -- (.2,0) arc (0:60:.2) -- cycle;
\draw[<-,red,line width=1pt] (60:1) -- (60:1 |- x);
\draw (0,0) -- (60:2);
%tangent
%\draw[<-,green,line width=1pt] (60:2) -- (1,0);
\draw[<-,green,line width=1pt] (1,\YValue) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also removed the redundant `\draw (0,0) -- (60:1);` as that line gets overwritten by `\draw (0,0) -- (60:2);`.